# Doubly bent arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a doubly bent arrow with arbitrary thickness, but I do not seem to be successful in getting my desired thickness. Currently, I only use

```
\draw[->,bend left, double,line width=2pt] (4.5,5.5) to (4.5,2);
```

But this has two problems:

1. `line width` only changes the thickness of the lines not the thickness
   of the actual arrow (i.e. the distance between the two parallel
   lines).
2. One side of the arrow is open, I need to have a line on
   this side to have closed arrow

Comment: Welcome! While code fragments are useful in explanations, it is always better to post a complete small document people can cut-paste-compile.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[length=8mm]}]
\draw[<->,bend left, double,double distance=5pt,line width=2pt] (4.5,5.5) to (4.5,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

To control distance between the double lines, use the key `double distance=<length>` and to have arrows on both ends, use the `<->` option.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean something like this?

[image: closed arrow]

This is what I'd think of as closing the arrow. You can adapt the other arrow as you wish. I've used `Stealth[]` as an example.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[{Butt Cap[length=-3pt]}-{Stealth[width=15pt,length=20pt]}, bend left, double, double distance=4pt, line width=2pt] (4.5,5.5) to (4.5,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```